# How to remove hours from datetime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to map through old db and take the dates which are in 2014-08-01 format and add them to the new DB. However, in the new DB along with the date default time is set,example 2014-10-06 00:00:00.0000000

```
newContract.ContractDate = DateTime.Parse(dataReader[2].ToString());
newContract.EndDate = DateTime.Parse(dataReader[3].ToString());
```

I tried like this:

```
newContract.ContractDate = DateTime.Parse(dataReader[2].ToString("yyyy-mm-DD"));
```

but I got error message:

```
Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments ODWE
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Side note: `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(dataReader[2].ToString());` - do you really have DateTime (`date`, etc.) values stored as `string`s (`char`, `varchar` etc.) in the RDBMS?

Comment: Dates are binary types, they have no format. Formats apply to strings. Which, by definition, are not dates.  Almost all databases (except SQLite) have date types. What is the *actual* type of the database fields? You may not have to do anything except **remove .ToString()**. After all, that call is **only** needed if `dataReader[2]` is *not* a string but an actual DateTime already

Comment: You're _probably_ looking for the [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-6.0) property of the `DateTime` struct.

Comment: Have you tried just `newContract.ContractDate = dataReader.GetDateTime(2);` ? Or `newContract.ContractDate = (DateTime)dataReader[2];` ? If the stored value contains a time you want to remove use `DateTime.Date` after retrieving the value.

Comment: Dmitry, yes they are DateTime stored

Comment: `in the new DB along with the date default time is set,example 2014-10-06 00:00:00.0000000` that's fine, if that's the actual date type used in the database field, eg a `datetime2(7)`. You can't change that. `datetime2` has no format, it's a binary value, just like an `int` or `numeric(18,7)`. If you don't want time, use a `date` field. This has nothing to do with formats. The `date` type in SQL Server (and other databases) stores only dates.

Comment: @Maria the string you see is nothing more than the binary value displayed in a format decided by the client application. If you want to only store dates use a date-only type *in the new database*. Don't convert the values to strings, this can only *cause* problems

Comment: Panagiotis, the result is the same. it still has 00:00:00 after the date

Comment: It looks like you've ignored the part of Panagiotis's comment where he advised you *not* to convert to a string representation. It's not clear what you mean by "it still has" (*what* still has?) but that definitely sounds like a string representation to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is coming from the fact that you are trying to format an object which is not a datetime.

`dataReader[2]` is not a DateTime, it's an object that you are parsing as a string using `toString()` but the `toString()` from object does not allow you to format.

And the default time is normal, that's the way datetime are stored because as the name suggest, it's date and time not only date. You cannot save only date in DateTime you can only have the time set to 00:00:00.0000000, but in your code you can format your `newContract.ContractDate.ToString("yyyy MMMM dd")` to display the date the way you want.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want only date.

```
newContract.ContractDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataReader[2]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: That will fail to compile, just as the OP's attempt failed to compile.

Comment: I Updated code , Please try again

Comment: Right. That's now a string that only represents a date, but it looks like the `ContractDate` property is a `DateTime`, not a `string`. (Fundamentally, I believe any string-based answer here is going to be inappropriate...)

Comment: You can't save only date in Datetime is this impossible)

Comment: Indeed. Or rather, you can't do better than saying "only look at the date; the time is midnight". Which is why there's discussion in a comment. But an answer that won't compile because the OP has confusing requirements doesn't really help.